# Sendmail alias file escape character

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

i am trying to configure sendmail alias to escape '@' to treat it as a user for example

test\@domain.com:test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com

I have user user test@domain.com in virtusertable as
test@gmail.com test\@gmail.com
and in passwd file as
test@viasites.com:x:UID:GID:viasites.com:/home/test:/bin/pop

if i remove @ sign everything works fine.The virtusertable is working fine with escape character '\'.But alias is not.

Is there a way where i can get alias working ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in /etc/mail/aliases when virtusertable exists for this reason?

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/mail/aliases you cannot have @ on the left hand side. The left hand side is considered a local name, hence no @ sign is expected there.